# Medial Axis Transform/Skeletonization on morphological for calculating numbers of component

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, diplib

I'm trying to calculate the number components on opencv library "connectedComponentsWithStats" in python, but my skeletonization result seems not do well, cause the number of component return incorrect result.
Here my original image to convert to skeleton.
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzEtB.png)

And here's my code as below,

## **Code**

```
import cv2
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import diplib as dip

def skel_trans(img):
    size = np.size(img)
    skel = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)

    element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
    done = False

    while( not done):
        eroded = cv2.erode(img,element)
        temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
        temp = cv2.subtract(img,temp)
        skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
        img = eroded.copy()

        zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
        if zeros==size:
            done = True

    return skel

threshold_value = 128  
max_value = 255  
select_map = cv2.imread('map.bmp', 0)
_, selected_map_binary = cv2.threshold(select_map, threshold_value, max_value, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

selected_map_binary_temp = selected_map_binary.copy()
I = np.ones((selected_map_binary.shape[0], selected_map_binary.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)


for rows in range (selected_map_binary_temp.shape[0]):
    for cols in range (selected_map_binary_temp.shape[1]):
        if(selected_map_binary_temp[rows, cols] > threshold_value):
            selected_map_binary_temp[rows, cols] = 1
        else:
            selected_map_binary_temp[rows, cols] = 0

image = cv2.bitwise_xor(selected_map_binary_temp,I)

for rows in range (image.shape[0]):
    for cols in range (image.shape[1]):
        if(image[rows, cols] == 1):
            image[rows, cols] = 255

#DipLib EuclideanSkeleton
dip_img = dip.Image(image)
bin = image > threshold_value
sk = dip.EuclideanSkeleton(bin)

#skel_trans
test_skel = skel_trans(image)
cv2.imshow('test_skel', test_skel)

dip.Show(sk)
input("Press Enter to continue...")

num_components, labeled_image, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(test_skel, connectivity=8)

print("Return num_components for the image" , num_components)
```

I tried the "medial_axis" in morphology and "EuclideanSkeleton" in DIPlib , the numbers of component still incorrect, after all I reference the [Skeletonization using OpenCV-Python](https://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/)
and try it in same input, the result still have problem on ellipse in the binary image,

[result of skeletonizetion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcIxf.png)

It still effect to the connectedComponentsWithStats of num_components, how can I fix this?

## **Expected result**

I check the matlab using "bwmorph(bw1,'skel',inf);" the skeleton will do well to the input and the numbers of conponents is 8.

[matlab result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0hFr.png)

Comment: The objects are black in your input image. So for the DIPlib case you need to do `bin = image < threshold_value`. The “true” pixels in the binary image must the be object pixels. It looks like you were computing the skeleton of the background, which has a single component.

Comment: As I’ve stated many times before, the OpenCV code that uses erosions and dilations (or openings) and bitwise or, doesn’t compute a skeleton, it finds a subset of points on the medial axis. It does not attempt to preserve connectivity.

Comment: One more comment: every time you loop over the pixels of an image, step back and think whether it’s actually necessary. Using NumPy it often is not (and remember OpenCV uses NumPy arrays as images). For example the case where you change pixels with a value of 1 to be 255, you can do `image[image==1] = 255`. Obviously using DIPlib the same syntax applies, as it does in Pandas and many other data-intensive packages.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks to your remind and suggestion , after spending more time on reviewing DIPlib library, the EuclideanSkeleton set in endPixelCondition = "three neighbors"  solve my problem.

Comment: Try Skimage skeletonize

Comment: Please don’t edit “solved” in the title. Instead, post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

add more optional in EuclideanSkeleton with endPixelCondition = "three neighbors could solved.